# Cannot read property addEventListener of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an `img` element, on click I want it to transform into an `iframe` (embedded video). I have assigned a `ref` to the element and also, I attach an event listener to the element when the component mounts.

The problem I am experiencing is that I am not seeing the changes I expect. I am getting an error `Cannot read property addEventListener of null` in the console. On clicking the image nothing happens, I assume either the event listener is not attached or the handler method is not working properly. What am i doing wrong here?

Functional component

```
export const ViewOneCourse = ({
  embedDiv,
  embedVideo
}) => {

  return (
    <div>
        <Grid item lg={5} md={5}>
          <div className="course-brick">
            <div
              className="youtube-video-place embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3 "
              data-yt-url="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BjngNWP9C5s?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1"
              ref={embedDiv}
            >
              <img
                src={video.poster}
                async
                className="play-youtube-video"
                ref={embedVideo}
              ></img>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Grid>
       </div>
  )      
}
```

Container

```
export class ViewCourse extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.embedVideo = React.createRef();
    this.embedDiv = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const embedVideo = this.embedVideo.current;
    if (embedVideo) {
      embedVideo.addEventListener("click", this.handleEmbedVideo);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    const embedVideo = this.embedVideo.current;
    if (embedVideo) {
      embedVideo.removeEventListener("click");
    }
  }

  handleEmbedVideo = () => {
    const video_wrapper = this.embedDiv.current;
    const embedUrl = video_wrapper.getAttribute("data-yt-url");
    //  Check to see if youtube wrapper exists
    if (video_wrapper.length) {
      video_wrapper.innerHTML =
        '<iframe allowfullscreen frameborder="0" class="embed-responsive-item" src="' +
        embedUrl +
        '"></iframe>';
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ViewOneCourse 
      embedDiv={this.embedDiv} 
      embedVideo={this.embedVideo} 
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the error you are getting? because your code makes sure that `embedVideo ` is not null before calling `addEventListener`: `...if (embedVideo) {...`

Comment: I had made a slight modification in the code after posting it here but the code above raises no error. Your answer corrected the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is with how you are checking whether the video wrapper exists or not:

```
if (video_wrapper.length) {
...
}
```

You should check if `video_wrapper` is truthy or not, instead of checking the property `length`:

```
if (video_wrapper) {
...
}
```

Also, there is a better approche to do this other than using refs.
You can add a state variable to `ViewCourse`, something like `showIframe`, and pass it down to `ViewOneCourse`, then inside `ViewOneCourse` you would use that variable (`showIframe`) to render either the image or the iframe.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4bkuvowd/)

Comment: In your demo, I noticed you bind the handleEmbedVideo method in the constructor. Do you mind explaining why? I thought arrow methods don't need binding

Comment: You're right, arrow functions don't need binding.
The reason I didn't use arrow functions, is that in my demo I didn't have babel configured to use class properties. (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties)

Answer (score 0):

In your container video_wrapper is an HTMLDivElement, your checking for length on it which returns undefined. Hence the check on video_wrapper.length fails, therefore the if block never executes.
you can try the following snippet

```
if (video_wrapper) {
        video_wrapper.innerHTML =
            '<iframe allowfullscreen frameborder="0" class="embed-responsive- 
           item" src="' +
            embedUrl +
            '"></iframe>';
    }
```

Hope this helps.